# Is there a way to change linked html page from code behind?

Tags: html, asp.net, email

I want to send a mail to the user when they forget their pw. For now my code works great. But currently my mail body is so simple and I want to do some make up for my e-mail body.

Currently my mail is a single line as =

```
msg.Body = "Testing the automatic mail <a href='surveyportal.site/PasswordForget.aspx?token=" + token + "' >New Password</a>";
```

On my /assets/ folder I have my mail body as mailbody.html.

I want to link "msg.Body" to my "/assets/mailbody.html/"
By the way everytime I need to change my button in mailbody.html according to my token.

So is there anyway to do so?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to load the content of mailbody.html into your message body? If so, then you can easily do that - read the contents of the file as text and assign/append that to the Body parameter.

Comment: Actually what I want to do is a bit more than that. I need to change href attribute of my anchor tag in mailbody.html to a different link every time. Because every token is different for every time user forgets password.

Comment: So? Load it into a string as ADyson described. Then replace a placeholder in the text with the actual token via a simple string replacement, before assigning it ot the email body.

Answer (score -2):

Okay I have found my answer over here. I am leaving the link if someone need it. https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-HTML-Page-File-as-Email-Body-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx